# Rails, how to post a form to Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to allow an admin on my app to sign in as any user. I found the following on the devise wiki:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  # Sign in as another user if you are an admin
  def become
    return unless current_user.is_an_admin?
    sign_in(:user, User.find(params[:id]))
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

In the view, how do you build a form to post to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't even need to build a form, you could simply allow the admin to go to the following url:

example.com/admin/become?id=25

where 25 is the id you want to log into as.

So with this method, you would just create a link for an admin to click on.

Comment: That's true but I think having a form would be nice :)

Comment: Also that erros with; Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for AdminController

Comment: ok woops I forgot to update my routes... Strange, now It's erroring with undefined method `find' for Admin:Class

Comment: Specifically load_and_authorize_resource, not sure where inside though or why

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'm unfortunate not familiar with Cancan.