# undefined method `find' for Admin:Class  --- CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

Has anyone seen this error:

```
undefined method `find' for Admin:Class
```

When using Devise and CanCan?

I'm unable to isolate where this is erroring: The logs are showing nothing useful:

```
Started GET "/admin/become?id=3" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Apr 06 13:09:15 -0700 2011
  SQL (0.3ms)  SHOW client_min_messages
  SQL (0.2ms)  SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'
  SQL (0.5ms)  SET standard_conforming_strings = on
  SQL (0.2ms)  SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
  SQL (0.4ms)  SET time zone 'UTC'
  SQL (0.1ms)  SHOW TIME ZONE
  Processing by AdminController#become as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Completed   in 57ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `find' for Admin:Class):


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.9ms)
  Permission Load (2.5ms)  SELECT * FROM "permissions" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "permissions"."group_id" WHERE ("permissions"."user_id" = 2) ORDER BY groups.name ASC
  SQL (1.3ms)   SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM pg_tables
 WHERE tablename = 'groups'
```

Application Trace:

```
cancan (1.5.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:102:in `find_resource'
cancan (1.5.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:67:in `load_resource_instance'
cancan (1.5.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:31:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.5.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:24:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.5.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:9:in `send'
cancan (1.5.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:9:in `_callback_before_35483'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `_run__22524425__process_action__2106917469__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
```

Comment: Have you tried going in to a rails console and doing the same thing? What is the output there? Also, I assume you're doing an Admin.find(3)?

Comment: @Chris, how would I do this in the console. I'm not doing an Admin.find, See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572015/rails-how-to-post-a-form-to-devise/5572059#5572059

Comment: Do you have an Admin user type? Have you ever generated one? Or do you only have the "User" class available to you, for users?

Comment: I have a USER table not an ADMIN table. In the user table I have an admin field that's a boolean. I do have an admin controller and model but the model is empty. class Admin 

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background: See the comments above in the question, including the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572015/rails-how-to-post-a-form-to-devise/5572059#5572059), and [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin) for details.

Your problem stems from not having a Devise based Admin class. I gleaned this information from the NoMethodFound error. This means that you are unable to use any kind of ActiveRecord methods on it, which the base implementation is trying to do. You'll probably want to replace this line of code...

```
return unless current_user.is_an_admin?
```

with something like this...

```
return unless current_user.admin == true
```

(or something that can be found in your User model's table)

Comment: That's an incredibly thoughtful answer. Thank you! I'd up vote 3 times if I could. I gave that a try but it still error'd with "undefined method `find' for Admin:Class" and "current_user.admin" is valid bec I'm using that elsewhere. if I comment everything out inside the become method it still errors, so I think it's something with CanCan

Comment: Happy to help, and.. Hm! Can you post the contents of the AdminController in your question? Does it have a before filter that tries to do something like authenticate_admin! or something in that venue?

Comment: So far I've isolated it down to this... If I comment this out it works, but then the admin controller is open to everyone: In the AdminController :  load_and_authorize_resource #CanCan

Comment: I'm wondering if CanCan isn't expecting some kind of Admin model (under the hood). I don't have much (read: any) experience with CanCan. It seems like it's authorize! method is a bit convoluted. I'm wondering if you couldn't come up with some kind of inheritance based ActiveRecord that could just be used for Admin's only.. Is that even an option? Or is splitting your Admin's in to another table even an option for you?

Comment: ya it's definitly CanCan, I need to somehow authorize the admin model through the user model. I should probably start a CanCan question for that.